# Which is better approach for managing photo numbers in a Django application?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm building a Django application that has includes feature that will allow users to upload photos and view other users' photos.  Each photo can be either a public photo viewable by all users or private one that's only viewable by a select set of other users.  What would be the best way to store the numbers (i.e. "indicies") associated with the photos?  Would I get better performance and scalability by storing them in Unix files or by storing them in a PostgreSQL array field which is accessed via the Django ArrayField type?  The indicies would only be written to when a user uploads photos but they would be read quite frequently when other users are viewing someone's photos.

Here are the two options in more detail:

If user "smith" uploads two public photos and one private photo, they will have these names:

```
smith_public_001.jpg
smith_public_002.jpg
smith_private_001.jpg
```

I could store '001' and '002' in a 'public_indicies' file and '001' in a separate 'private_indicies' file:

```
smith
├── private
│   ├── private_indicies.txt
│   └── smith_private_001.jpg
└── public
    ├── public_indicies.txt
    ├── smith_public_001.jpg
    └── smith_public_002.jpg
```

Alternately, I could have an 'Indicies' Django class like this and store them there:

```
class Indicies(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  pub_indicies = ArrayField(
    models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True), 
    null=True)
  pvt_indicies = ArrayField(
    models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True), 
    null=True)
```

The "naive" approach would be to store them in files.  Intuitively this makes sense to me as file reads and writes should be very fast and the database is ultimately just reading and writing files to a disk too but using a database adds the extra overhead of both the database and the Django ORM.  One might say that saving indicies to a file isn't scalable because you're tieing all your indicies to a particular server but if I ever got enough user photos that my static photo media server was getting hammered, I could create multiple photo servers and spread my users' photos and their index files across the servers.

By the way, I've thought about using Django raw SQL queries but constructing the query string is pretty messy.  I could also store the indicies in a NoSQL database like Redis but that has the disadvantage that the indicies would only be persisted to disk once a minute.  If my server were to crash, the indicies could be in a bad state which could screw up my index management code.

I should add that users will be limited to uploading 10 public photos and 10 private ones.  Thus, the use case is an occasional small write and very frequent small reads.

What am I missing?  What are the benefits and drawbacks to these two approaches in terms of performance and scalability?  Is there another better approach I haven't thought of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading/writing to files is essentially the slowest thing there is in modern computation. I don't remember the numbers, but it is something like a 1000 times slower than memory access.

A database management system does store everything on the disk, but when you communicate with it, most of the time you are talking to the in-memory copy. The dump to the drive happens in the background.

So, from the performance perspective, as well as from the organisational point of view, using a database is preferable.

Comment: Thanks Maksim.  I hadn't considered the possibility that the database would be holding the data in memory.